# Xcompmgr, puts child windows in the background

Tags: window, fluxbox

I don't know if it's related to fluxbox, but whenever I launch the transparency management at startup with `xcompmgr -f` it becomes difficult to use pop-up windows. They are all sent to background, and the main application windows remains on the top.

It's pretty unusable with applications that have much use of pop-up windows.
If I don't launch xcompmgr, the window behaviour is ok.

Any idea what to check, or to do ?